# Dynamic PHP FORM creation based on MySQL Column Data Types

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How can I know the type of each column extracted from a DB with "select" so I can dynamically add the right input type in my form?

Comment: You can get schema information from the aptly named `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-schema.html

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to do this; neither is perfect, but both will work.

First, if you know the table and column name, you can do this:

```
SELECT data_type, character_maximum_length, numeric_precision 
  FROM information_schema.COLUMNS
 WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = DATABASE()
   AND TABLE_NAME='table'
   AND COLUMN_NAME='column'
```

This will give you back some basic information you need to construct a field, given the `table` and `column` name in the present data base.  The values of `data_type` include the following:

```
bigint     64-bit integer
char       fixed length character string
datetime   date and time
decimal    decimal
double     64-bit IEEE-754 floating point
enum       enumerated type (small integer)
float      32-bit IEEE-754 floating point
geometry   Geo extension type
int        32-bit integer
longblob   binary large object, up to 4 gigabytes in size
longtext   text large object, up to 4 gigabytes in size
mediumblob binary large object, up  16 megabytes in size
mediumint  integer in range [0-16 megabytes]
mediumtext text large object, up to 16 megabytes
smallint   integer [0-65535]
text       text large object, up to 64k bytes
time       time of day
timestamp  UNIX style timestamp
tinyint    integer [0-255]
tinyblob   binary "large" object up to 255 bytes
tinytext   text "large" object up to 255 bytes
varchar    variable length character string
```

Second, when you fetch a result set from an RDMS (MySQL or some other) using a SELECT statement, you always get back some information -- some metadata -- that describes the columns.  You can use mysqli::fetch_fields or the equivalent call in other apis to retrieve that. In this case, you'll get back coded values, as described here:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-fields.php